# RecyclerView Images keeps refreshing when scroll up and down, Us

Tags: android-recyclerview

```
  public class Adapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter1.ViewHolder>  {
ArrayList<CategoryModels> categoryList;
Context context;

public Adapter1(ArrayList<CategoryModels> categoryList, Context context){
    this.categoryList =categoryList;
    this.context = context;

}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_scategory_single_layout,null);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        CategoryModels categoryModels = categoryList.get(position);

    holder.name.setText(categoryModels.getName());

    int pos = getItemViewType(position);
    if(categoryList.get(pos).getImage() == null) {

        holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else
        new DownloadImageTask(holder.image).execute(baseurl+categoryModels.getImage());
        //Picasso.with(categoryList.ge).load("http://www.zawallpaper.com/includes/images/"+categoryModels.getImage()).resize(120, 60).into(holder.image);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return categoryList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView name;
    ImageView image;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgcategory);
    }
}
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }


    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        //ProgressDialogue.hideProgressDialogue();
    }


}
public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString) {
    try {
        byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

I know this question has been asked before . But i could not resolve my issue. I am getting data in form of json . images are loading through a async task . but when ever i scroll up or down imges get replaced on one another and then after some seconds, images are displayed in their original position. i think the problem is in OnBind Method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make api call in onBind
1. make api call in activity 
2. & in `onPostExecute`{} Set adapter

```
recyclerview.setAdapter(new YourAdapter(dataList))<br>
```

If you want to make Api call on scrolling of list, write logic in onScroll method

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener
```

If you want to change images wrt position of recyclerview Use any image loading library: ex: square
http://square.github.io/picasso/

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(view);
```

Comment: i am already calling api  in activity where iam getting all the data, in aync task im just loading the imag with a url.  the problem is when ever i scroll up or down, images get replaced on one other. is there anyway to strickly bind the images in their postiion whenever i scroll up or down?

Comment: i used piccasso. but it gives error. Context must not be null

Comment: Well , i have solved the issue regarding to picasso and it solved the scrolling problem. Thanks for your help. :)